# Google bigquery Web UI: change height of the "New Query" box?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

This is hardly a programming question, so please don't laugh me out of here.  On the Google bigquery Web UI, is there a way to make the "New Query" box taller?  I have been getting into fairly length queries and I would like to be able to see them all at once.  Or should I be graduating to a different mechanism (python?) for writing and running queries?  Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try dragging the grey line just under the big red "Run Query" button.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Resizing query panel in BigQuery]

(what @user3594923 said, in animated form)